# Transparency parameter of colors (vector, legend,...) not working in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

[image]It's a pity that QGIS offers to set transparency in the selecting color tool, but doesn't save it...

Explanation :
I guess that the AA (in French, sorry) in #RRVVBBAA would enable to set transparency (0% => AA = 00 ; 50% => AA = 80 ; 100% => AA = FF).
The same thing with rgba (r, g, b, a) where QGIS doesn't allow to set a <> 1.

For printing issues, I would like to have a black 50%, it would be possible by setting #00000080 or rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.50 ) but QGIS re-set theses values back to #000000ff and rgba( 0, 0, 0, 1.00 )...

If there is no way to do this thing now, do you think it will be improved in a next version ?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question per question.

Comment: What version of QGIS you have? In the screenshot there is completely missing opacity bar. Might be because of text/resolution scaling or something similar. If you switch to rgba you can surely set something like rgba( 0, 255, 0, 0.50 ) - 50% opacity and when clicking on opacity bar the transparency value is changed.

Comment: I use QGis Wien 2.8.2

Comment: Polygeo, I deleted my second question, so you can answer the first one ;-)

Comment: Thank you Miro 10, "tu n'es pas miro" (= you don't have a bad eyesight, in very bad French language...) so you saw the missing opacity bar which is not in QGis Wien 2.8.2 but in QGis 2.8.3   But unfortunately, even in 2.8.3, this opacity bar is not in the color selector of the map composer... it would have been great to set opacity to 0.5 to the texts of my legend...

Answer (score 2):

Not all color pickers everywhere support alpha values. Based on your thread title, I guess that you're working somewhere in the legend so I went to the print composer, added a legend, and indeed: the font color does not support an alpha value.

After looking some more, it seems like alpha values cannot be set for font colors anywhere. I don't know if there is a technical reason or if it has just been overlooked.

[image]

Tested in 2.12

Comment: Very good catch. I completely did not realize there can be different windows for picking color in different tools. What can be helpful in some cases is that this is in print composer where objects have under item properties part "Rendering" and there is Transparency bar. Sure this will apply to the whole object and not only to font.

Comment: Unfortunately, even in 2.8.3, this opacity bar is not in the color selector of the map composer... it would have been great to set opacity to 0.5 to the texts of my legend...

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question "will it be improved in the next version?" is, yes. I am running QGIS Wien 2.8.3 and my colour tools look like this:

[image: QGIS colour tools in 2.8.3]

There is the opacity slider as well as the options to change the HTML notation format.

Comment: There should be no change in features between 2.8.2 and 2.8.3 ... so that's a little weird.

Comment: OK but, even in 2.8.3, this opacity bar is not in the color selector of the map composer... so no way to set texts opacity < 1 :-(

Comment: Ah - it wasn't obvious from the original question that you were trying to set transparency/opacity on text.  What if you select the legend in Composer and then go to Rendering Properties and set the blend mode to Multiply and, optionally, set the transparency? It does work on the whole legend though so may have to create two legend items - one with symbols only and one with text only.

Comment: Good idea, I did it (I copied/pasted my legend, deleted the text for one of them, set the other one to 50% transparency and sent it to back) but it's quite long for something that could be managed in the color manager of the text only... The bad thing is that there is no point to do that if PDF cannot be exported in CMYK colors...